# Doubts with ps4 accounts

Tags: ps4, psn

So I made My first PSN account back in 2010, I realised that by accident I set my account to be Spanish rather than Mexican. I had a few trophies on My spanish account so I made a Mexican account, bought games on that one and played them on my "main" account. I recently got a ps4 and I already linked both My main spanish account and the Mexican one I use to buy stuff. My question Is, can I do the same with the ps4 as I did with the Ps3? Let's say I buy The Walking dead and it's episodes on My Mexican account, will I be able to play them on My Spanish account? I searched other places For answers and I just want to be 100% sure. I already know that I can share PS plus but I'm not so with dlc, expansions, mapa, etcetera. I appreciate any comments of somebedy reads this.

Answer (score 2):

If you activate a PS4 as "primary" for a PSN account then you can play any game that account owns regardless of what account is currently signed in to the PS4.

For example, if you purchase "The Walking Dead" with your Mexican account, and that account has activated the PS4 as "primary", then you can sign in with your Spanish account and play "The Walking Dead", earning trophies, using DLC, etc. with no limits.

Note that if you were to sign into some other PS4 with your Mexican account, and not make that PS4 primary (for instance, at a friend's house), you could download the games, but no other account could play them.

You can only have a single primary account.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of PSN. Your Playstation device does not affect this. PSN and your Playstation console are separate things. You will be able to do this with a PS4.

Comment: Sweet, thanks For the answer, really appreciate it!

Comment: If this works for you, please click the check mark next to the post to signify that it is the answer.